fbpanel: increase text size
I am using fbpanel on debian. In the config file ~/.config/fbpanel/default, I have this section which defines the "start menu":
Plugin {
    type = menu
    config {
        IconSize = 26
        image = /usr/share/pixmaps/debian-logo.png
        systemmenu {
        }
        separator {
        }
        item {
            name = logout
            icon = application-exit
            action = killall -u testuser --quiet
        }
    }
}

I am able to change the icon size, but how do I increase the text size?
The text size is too small.

I am also using openbox, in case that is relevant

You can add something like this to your ~/.gtkrc-2.0 for font size 40:
gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans 40"

That's because fbpanel uses the old GTK. You can also set other properties there, like:
gtk-icon-theme-name = "Adwaita"
gtk-theme-name = "Adwaita"

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GTK#GTK_2

Since fbpanel itself does not offer a setting for font size, the font size cannot be changed directly within fbpanel.
Documentation for fbpanel project
1. ~/.fbpanel/default
I found a post suggesting to add the following line in the global section of ~/.fbpanel/default to adjust the font and size:
font = Sans 12
However, this will not work!
2.~/.gtkrc-2.0
One solution is to adjust the settings through GTK in the ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file, as suggested in the first answer.
In fbpanel, GTK is responsible for the graphical user interface, including the display of fonts, icons, menus, and other graphical elements.
Since fbpanel is based on GTK2, the GTK configuration also controls the appearance of fonts and colors in the panel.
How to set font and theme for GTK+2 programs from the command-line on Linux?
Font sizes within gtk2 & qt programs
enu font size too small to read
How can I change the font size in GTK?
3. GTK2_RC_FILES

Create a custom gtkrc config (e.g. ~/.fbpanel-gtkrc) for fbpanel and set your font (or any style) settings in there:

style "custom-font" {
  font_name = "Sans 16"
}
class "*" style "custom-font"

change gtk-2 font only for specific application
4. Other options include trying one of the four listed:

Set DPI
~/.Xresources
xrdb
xrandr

Check out the post for details and see what you can find in search engines for each individual point.
How to scale the resolution/display of the desktop and/or applications?
5. Installing a different theme
Another thing you can try is simply installing a different theme.
Also, search for tips, tricks, and hacks in search engines.
https://blog.spiralofhope.com/1206/fbpanel.html#changing-the-theme
6. Adjustment possibly through CSS
Openbox/Fbpanel, How to set it all up.
7. Using fontconfig
Another method is to control the font size through fontconfig over xml.
You can create a ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf file.
fontconfig is older than the GTK configuration file, which applies to GTK2, and it’s possible that if you make changes here, GTK might simply ignore them and use its own settings instead.
About Fontconfig
Font configuration
And with the settings, you should always consider the cache of fontconfig.
What is the purpose of fc-cache in fontconfig?
In most cases, GTK might simply ignore the settings and use its own settings instead.
